# additionalViewData id will not overwrite editorfor auto generated id when using properties from an object within my view model

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-4

My Quesiton: Within my view model I created a class `InterfaceDisplay` that houses some display properties and other meta data for setting up my interface entry form.

I'm wondering why when I set a custom id using the additionalViewData object, ex. `@Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.DependantSystem, new { @id = "ls" })` is my control id still set to the auto generated `id="Interface_DependantSystem"` I've overwritten ids from properties straight from the ViewModel but when they are properties within an object no dice.

My View Model:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    //Other Properties

    public class InterfaceDisplay {
        [DisplayName("Linked System")]
        public string DependantSystem { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Data Flow")]
        public string DataFlow { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Method")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View

```
@model Namespaces.ApplicationViewModel
<table class="content-table">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 240px;">
                @Html.Hidden("appid", @Model.Id)

                @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Interface.DependantSystem)
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.DependantSystem, new { @id = "ls" })

                @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Interface.DataFlow)
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.DataFlow, new { @id = "df" })

                @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Interface.Type)
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.Type, new { @id = "mt" })

                @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Interface.Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.Name, new { @id = "nm" })

                @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Interface.Description)
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Interface.Description, new { @id = "de" })
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument that you are passing to the `EditorFor` helper is defining an additional view data for the corresponding editor template. But if you don't write a custom editor template, then the [`default template`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) will be used. And as you can see from the blog post I've linked to in my previous sentence, this default template does absolutely nothing with the additional view data property argument that you are passing to it.

So if you want this parameter to have some effect you will have to write a custom template - an editor template in your case, because you are using the EditorFor helper. Since you are applying it to a property of a string type (`Description`) you could add the following custom editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml` with the following contents:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    ViewData
)
```

Notice how I have overriden the default template and passed the ViewData as third argument to the TextBox helper so that the anonymous object you created in your view as second argument to the EditorFor helper ends up as HTML attributes of the corresponding input field that this template will generate.

Now since you have overriden the default editor template for the string type whenever you use `Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfTypeString, new { @class = "foo", id = "bar" })`, this custom template will be used instead of the default one and it will generate the following markup for you:

```
<input class="foo" id="bar" name="Description" type="text" value="some value" />
```

Comment: So does modelbinding happen off of the Name property of a control or the id of a control? i think what was confusing me is that i supplied @Name="somename" via additional view data of a @html.dropdownfor() and then my binding worked like i wanted it too, and then when trying to do it with an ID it wasnt working, and i was kind of getting them confused.

Comment: Model binding happens on the **name** property. But beware, HTML helpers do not allow you to override the name property. So it's pretty meaningless to write `{ name = "foobar" }`, because that's gonna get ignored. What you should be doing instead is designing your view models in such a way that the naming convention is respected.

Comment: Sounds good, I was sort of forced into writing the viewmodel the proper way in order to get it all to work. Thanks a bunch for the info, learned a few things, much appreciated.